# Index out bound en Matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

Cree esta funcion in Matlab entonces cuando la llamo desde el CLI(GUI) y le doy un argumento me sale error index out of bound.
LLamada desde el CLI(GUI)

```
>> volt(1)
ans = -0.1918
>> volt(2)
error: index (2): out of bound 1 (dimensions are 1x1)
error: called from
    volt at line 7 column 8
>>
```

Codigo de función

```
%Funcion que recibe como argumento el t y evalua la siguiente ecuacion 5^-t * sin(5t).
function r = volt(t)
     cincoElev = power(5,-(t)); %Elevamos el 5 a la -t y lo guardamos en la variable.
     obtSen = sin(5(t)); %Obtenemos el valor de seno de 5 * t y lo guardamos en la variable.
     r = cincoElev * obtSen; % Multiplicamos ambos resultados.
 end
```

Estoy buscando una explicación o solución.